# Changing row color in not-active DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

What's the best way of changing some rows back color in DataGridView, when **it's not active**??

In "real" world I would like to use it for formatting all DataGridView rows after button click, depending on some criterias.

To reproduce behaviour, please try:
1. In WinForms application put **TabControl** with two tab pages. On the first tab put **button**, on second - **DataGridView**.
2. Use following code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public int counter = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Surname", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add("Mark", "Spencer");
            dt.Rows.Add("Mike", "Burke");
            dt.Rows.Add("Louis", "Amstrong");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            this.Text = "Event counter: " + counter.ToString();

            dataGridView1.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

I put the **counter** variable for testing different options to see, how many times the event of color changing is fired (less is better ;) - ideally only once).

Now, when you first click the button WITHOUT going on tabPage2, and then you switch to tabPage2 - the color of row will not change. This is the problem I have.

It will work when you **first** activate tabPage2, and **then** press the button, or when you programatically set `tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;`, then color row and then switch back to `tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;` - but in this situation it "blinks".

I also tried to put code of color changing to **cell_painting** event, but for me it's overkill - it's fired couple hundred times in short time, even when you move mouse over datagridview, while I need to do it only once.

Do you have any advice how to solve that issue?

Best regards,
Marcin

Comment: @V4Vendetta: as the last solution - yes, but it's fired many, many times, waste of CPU time for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to the colour within the datagridview paint event (which gets fired when the tabpage changes).

```
private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

This works nicely for me - the paint event does get called several times when you change the tab, so if you want to only set the DefaultCellStyle once you could do something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private bool setcol;
    private bool painted;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setcol = true;
        painted = false;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (setcol && !painted)
        {
            painted = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mj82 one way of tidying this up would to subclass the datagridview control and then put this logic there (with perhaps a new property where you can set the backcolour)